# Not reinitialize variable inside While Loop

Tags: sql-server

I have created an stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and it contains the following code snippet:

```
WHILE (@COUNTER <= @COUNT_ROWSTOBEPROCESSED ) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @INFID AS INT =0;
        DECLARE @TPID AS INT =0;        
        SELECT @INFID = InfID FROM @TEMPTABLE WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = @COUNTER;
        print @INFID ;
            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;        
    END
```

But it gives me following result:

```
(106 row(s) affected)
0
-26
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0 all are zeros ....
```

I have already values in the temp table but it is not initialized into `@INFID` variable.

Why it is happening? I don't understand...

Please help me, if anyone have a solution.

----Comment---
yeap, I have seen into my code. But here I have already added counter increment in my code. but still i have same problem.
when i have run the below query inside the loop. i found that @@RowCount is always 1.

```
SELECT InfID,@ROWCOUNT FROM @TEMPTABLE WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = @COUNTER;
```

Can u tell me how to iterate each row of temptable using while loop or for loop in sql?

Comment: `WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = @COUNTER` is incorrect. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Won't `@@ROWCOUNT` change everytime that the `SELECT` statement is run, therefore, it will always select the first result?

Comment: This is a infinite loop becase `@COUNTER <= @COUNT_ROWSTOBEPROCESSED` have no changes.

Comment: @danihp - Good point. the counter doesn't even get incremented. But I assume it must in their actual code as otherwise the condition is either always true or always false.

Comment: Following your edit you would need to add an identity column to the table then use that in your where clause or use a cursor. But why are you doing this? Set based operations perform much better in SQL Server than ones iterating through row by row.

Comment: Hi Smith, 
I got it and i resolve my problem as per your comment.
Thank you, very much.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = @COUNTER` is incorrect.

`@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows affected by the previous statement.

It will only evaluate to `true` once. (When `@COUNTER` = 1) so the rest of the time no assignment  is made to `@INFID` from the `SELECT` operation.

What are you trying to do? My best guess is that you need to add an `IDENTITY` column to your table and reference that instead of `@@ROWCOUNT` or use a cursor.

But if you explain your end goal we may be able to tell you a set based way of achieving whatever your goal is without [RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) processing.